# Can this collection add Fragment codeblock become any simpler (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I wrote this code block to add a fragment when there are no fragments in the backstack. My code block however looks a lil clumsy. Can it be written in a better way?

```
with(supportFragmentManager) {
            takeIf { backStackEntryCount == 0 }
                    ?. apply {
                        with(beginTransaction()) {
                            add(R.id.container, FirstFragment())
                            commit()
                        }
                    }
        }
```

also, with(beginTransaction()) shows me lint warning that transaction should be committed(). I think it has to do with my incorrect implementation of it. Kindly tell me how to get rid of that lint warning.

**EDIT 1**

Not here but at certain places I do perform some other operations along with add(). Stuff like adding the fragment to backstack and providing custom Transitions.

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let {


            with(it.beginTransaction()) {
                setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                addToBackStack("second")
                replace(R.id.container, SecondFragment())
                commit()
            }

        }
```

Now there are a few methods that need to be called on FragmentTransaction object. This one is more suitable for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) { // replaces the `takeIf` things
       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                  .add(R.id.container, FirstFragment())
                  .commit()
}
```

Comment: I would say it's really beautiful. You remind me of days when I used to write such pretty code in JAVA. I would have accepted this answer but it reminds me of another usecase that is common. I have edited the answer. Can you try to another simplistic answer for that too?

Comment: I realised just now that we can chain addToBackStack() and addCustomTransitions() directly just like add() and commit(). Looks like your solution is the simplest. Moreover it hardly uses any of those fancy Kotlin features. Beauty is in simplicity. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

you know kotlin provide extension function feature that used to make easy way to add fragement like below code ..

```
        fun Fragment.addReportFragment(): Fragment {
        mFragment = ReportFragment()
        this.fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(if (this is ReportFragment) LOGIN_ROOT else MAIN_ROOT, mFragment, REPORT_FRAGMENT)?.commit()
        return mFragment as ReportFragment
    }
```

and simple way to used below code..

```
    var pickpowerfrag = PickPowerFragment()
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.ReplaceFrame, pickpowerfrag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```